# How to get field names when running plain sql query in django

Tags: python, django

In one of my django views I query database using plain sql (not orm) and return results.

```
sql = "select * from foo_bar"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I am getting the data fine, but not the column names. How can I get the field names of the result set that is returned?

Comment: This is a simplified example to illustrate that the column names are not known beforehand. So after I get the resultset I needed a way to retrieve the names of the columns as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), you can try using `cursor.description`, but this is not entirely reliable.

Comment: Why is this not reliable? Works for me. Should I be worried?

Comment: @user984003: "Cursor Objects **should** respond to the following methods and attributes." (emphasis mine)

Comment: "Not entirely reliable" is right. I'm getting cursors with None as their description.

Answer (score 26):

On the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), there's a pretty simple method provided (which does indeed use `cursor.description`, as Ignacio answered).

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Comment: @DataGreed That's great to hear, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: I have a left outer join. Any idea how to distinguish the table ? right now with this method i get column names as keys. the keys are from two tables. not able to distinguish whether a column is from which table.

Comment: I'm afraid it's been too long since I've worked with this for me to be able to say for sure, sorry. I think it would be worth creating a new question for.

Answer (score 7):

I have found a nice solution in Doug Hellmann's blog:

http://doughellmann.com/2007/12/30/using-raw-sql-in-django.html

```
from itertools import *
from django.db import connection

def query_to_dicts(query_string, *query_args):
    """Run a simple query and produce a generator
    that returns the results as a bunch of dictionaries
    with keys for the column values selected.
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query_string, query_args)
    col_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            break
        row_dict = dict(izip(col_names, row))
        yield row_dict
    return
```

Example usage:

```
  row_dicts = query_to_dicts("""select * from table""")
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following code :

```
def read_data(db_name,tbl_name): 
    details = sfconfig_1.dbdetails
    connect_string = 'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER={server}; DATABASE={database};UID={username}\
        ;PWD={password};Encrypt=YES;TrustServerCertificate=YES'.format(**details)

    connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)#connecting to the server
    print("connencted to db")
    # query syntax 

    query = 'select top 100 * from '+'[{}].[dbo].[{}]'.format(db_name,tbl_name) + ' t where t.chargeid ='+ "'622102*3'"+';'
    #print(query,"\n")
    df    = pd.read_sql_query(query,con=connection)
    print(df.iloc[0])

    return "connected to db...................."
```

Comment: please, remove this anwser from here...